# Vue 3 Composition API: Array.length Not Reactive

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm struggling to figure out how to make properties of an array reactive. Is this possible? In the example below, the `filteredResults` array itself is reactive, and working, but neither the `resultCountRef` (wrapped in `reactive()`) nor the `resultCount` fields are reactive. In otherwords, if I click the `Filter for Apples` button, the filteredResults changes to just the one item, but the two count fields remain at `3`. Note that using {{filteredResults.length}} in the template does work as expected. [Here is a working sample](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

And here is the code (a Search.vue composition API component, and a useFilter composition function):

`Search.vue:`

```js
<template>
  <div>resultCountRef: {{resultCountRef}}</div>
  <div>resultCount: {{resultCount}}</div>
  <div>filteredResults.length: {{filteredResults.length}}</div>
  <div>filteredResults: {{filteredResults}}</div>
  <div>filters: {{filters}}</div>
  <div><button @click="search()">Search</button></div>
  <div><button @click="applyFilter('apples')">Filter for Apples</button></div>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from 'vue';
import useFilters from './useFilters.js';

export default {
  setup(props) {
    const products = reactive(['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes']);
    const { filters, applyFilter, filteredResults } = useFilters(products);
    const resultCountRef = reactive(filteredResults.value.length);
    const resultCount = filteredResults.value.length;

    return {
      resultCountRef,
      resultCount,
      filteredResults,
      filters,
      applyFilter,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

`useFilters.js:`

```js
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

function filterResults(products, filters) {
  return products.filter((product) => filters.every(
    (filter) => {
      return product.includes(filter);
    },
  ));
}

export default function useFilters(products) {
  const filters = ref([]);
  const filteredResults = ref([...products]);
  const applyFilter = (filter) => {
    filters.value.push(filter);
    filteredResults.value.splice(0);
    filteredResults.value.splice(0, 0, ...filterResults(products, filters.value));
  };

  return { filters, applyFilter, filteredResults };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
const resultCountRef = reactive(filteredResults.value.length);
```

The reason why `reactive` is not working is because `filteredResults.value.length` returned a simple number and not referencing to anything.

From @JimCopper 's comment:

> The returned object is simply providing an observable object that wraps the object/value/array passed in (in my case the filteredResults.length value). That returned object resultCountRef  is the object that is tracked and can be then modified, but that's useless in my case and it's why reactive didn't work. )

---

As the `resultCount` depends on `filteredResults`, you can use `computed` to monitor the change

Here is [the modified playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
setup(props) {
    const products = reactive(['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes']);
    const { filters, applyFilter, filteredResults } = useFilters(products);
    // const resultCountRef = reactive(filteredResults.length); 
    const resultCount = computed(() => filteredResults.length) // use computed to react to filteredResults changes

    return {
      // resultCountRef,
      resultCount,
      filteredResults,
      filters,
      applyFilter,
    };
},
```

---

The new doc does not have a very nice explanation on computed so i just quote it from the [old doc explanation](https://012.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#:%7E:text=A%20computed%20property%20is%20used,the%20computed%20property%20has%20changed.)

> A computed property is used to declaratively describe a value that depends on other values. When you data-bind to a computed property inside the template, Vue knows when to update the DOM when any of the values depended upon by the computed property has changed.